# no-gutters no-padding not working to reduce gap between Bootstrap columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have searched through other Stackoverflow posts with similar issue. After reading them, I upgraded my CDN to Bootstrap 4, but still issue with extra spacing is not resolved. I think it is something to do with the col size maybe.

```
<div class="row no-gutters no-padding">
    <div class="col-sm-10 no-gutters no-padding">

        <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left no-gutters no-padding">
            <label class="control-label pull-left" for="CS">Contact Stream:  </label>
            <kendo-dropdownlist id="CS" [data]="CSEntries" style="width:80px"
                                [textField]="'CS'"
                                [valueField]="'CSID'"
                                (valueChange)="onCSEntriesChanged($event)">
            </kendo-dropdownlist>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 pull-left no-gutters no-padding">
            <label class="control-label" for="DateRange">Date Submitted Date Range: </label>
            <kendo-daterange>
                <label>

                    <kendo-dateinput kendoDateRangeStartInput [format]="'MM/dd/yyyy'" [(value)]="range.start"
                                     style="width:100px" autoCorrectOn="blur" (valueChange)="onChange($event)"></kendo-dateinput>
                </label>
                <label>

                    <kendo-dateinput kendoDateRangeEndInput [format]="'MM/dd/yyyy'"
                                     style="width:100px" autoCorrectOn="blur" [(value)]="range.end"></kendo-dateinput>
                </label>
                <kendo-daterange-popup>
                    <ng-template kendoDateRangePopupTemplate>
                        <kendo-multiviewcalendar kendoDateRangeSelection [format]="'MM/dd/yyyy'" [min]="min" [max]="max">
                        </kendo-multiviewcalendar>
                    </ng-template>
                </kendo-daterange-popup>

            </kendo-daterange>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1 pull-left no-gutters no-padding">
            <button type="button" (click)="dispProjects()" class="btn btn-primary">Display Projects</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried adding to css

```
padding-0 {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

and then replacing no-gutters no-padding with padding-0, but that doesn't work either. Please guide. here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: To have no padding, use the `p-0` class in your html. `<div class="col-sm-10 no-gutters p-0">`

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what's wrong here?

Comment: updated post with screenshot

Answer (score 0):

There is no `no-padding` class in Bootstrap 4. Did you mean `p-0`?

The `no-gutters` class belongs on the `row`, not the columns (`col-*`). Also, columns must be the immediate child of `row`. Don't nest columns directly inside other columns.